# How does the principle of conservation of energy for a phase-shifter transformer apply?

Tags: power, transformer, energy

Since the phase shifter transformer is used for regulating the real power  in the transmission line by means of changing the angle 
it leads to the fact that the real power at
the secondary side should become greater without injecting any more power 
and we will beat over load 
Now the question is where does this power come from?

Answer (score 1):

No, the real power on both sides is the same. If a [phase-shifting transformer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_booster) is used in "buck" mode in order to reduce the real power supplied to the load side, it also consumes less power from the supply side.